# Duplicate data transferring from Outsystems to SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, outsystems

I am new to Outsystems , I have a last mile app based on Outsystems wherein I scan shipment bags , identified by barcode, and the shipment data then moves to SalesForce. However, what is happening is, that when data is moving to SalesForce, I am getting duplicate Barcodes in SF. What could be the possible reason(s)?

I do not know how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

There could be a variety of issues that are causing your problem.
The first thing I would check is that the call to SalesForce that adds your barcode is only being executed once by your OutSystems UI and logic.
The other thing to check is if you are using a custom SalesForce API that the logic in your API is sound and only adding the barcode once.  You could try running a test with Postman or another API tool to see if adding a barcode directly causes a duplicate.
Beyond that I would need to see your OML file to be able to further pinpoint what the problem might be.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Greg's answer, I'd advise you to post questions in the [OutSystems forum](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/). You'll have the expertise of an entire community there, and chances are your questions get answered much quicker.